# Do logarithms appear inside the divergent UV integrals? If so why?

Tags: mathematics, integration

Do logarithms appear inside the UV divergent integrals of $q\cdot f\cdot t$?

I mean expressions of the form of $ \int_{V}d^{r}f(p)log(p^{2}+m^{2}) $

In this case, can we approximate it by  $ log(p)= \frac{p^{e}-1}{e} $?

Comment: What do you mean with *"Do logarithms appear in the UV divergent integrals"*?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose your title would rather be ; "... if *not*, why ?".
In momentum space (which I assume is the focus of your question), these do not appear; the integrals are made of Feynman propagators $(p^2+m^2+i\epsilon)$ in the denominator and in the numerator you find various tensor contractions of your loop momentum (or momenta) with the external momenta / polarisations.

Having a $\log$ in the integral would correspond to a highly non-local interaction involving infinitely many operators of the form $m^{2k}/p^{2k}$ for $k\in \mathbb Z$, as you see by power expanding your $\log$ in the $p^2>m^2$ and $p^{2}<m^2$ regions. While the $k>0$ terms correspond to higher derivative operators to include to the lagrangian, which may be interpreted as higher order operators of a UV theory, the negative powers produce non-local interactions which are not compatible with unitary in general, and with the optical theorem in particular.